# Leading zeros disappearing from string in html-attribute in Angular2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm having some issues outputing a string from an object to a html-attribute in Angular2. For some reason leading zeros disappear from the string when sent to a html-attribute, but not to innerHTML of the DOM-element.

Plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/yHdtjYs5Mh0aguFoS0Jl/

The data model:

```ts
export class Company{
  name:string;
  orgNr:string;
}
```

The component

```ts
export class App {
  public companies:Array<Company> = [];

  constructor() {
    let c = new Company();
    c.name = "Google";
    c.orgNr = "0000123";
    this.companies.push(c);
  }
}
```

The template:

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let company of companies" value="{{company.orgNr}}">
        {{company.name}} - {{company.orgNr}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

If the orgNr is set to "0000123" this is the value being displayed in the li-element, but in the value attribute the value is "123".

```html
<ul>
  <li value="123">
        Google - 0000123
  </li>
</ul>
```

Not really sure what's going on here, but I suspect it has something to do with type convertion. Is it a problem with Angular or is there something else I can do than always starting a number with something else than zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `value` needs to be integer, and only meaningful when used with `ol`, i.e. ordered list.
Quoting MDN:

> value
>
> This integer attribute indicates the current ordinal value of the list item as defined by the `<ol>` element. The only allowed value for this attribute is a number, even if the list is displayed with Roman numerals or letters. List items that follow this one continue numbering from the value set. The value attribute has no meaning for unordered lists (`<ul>`) or for menus (`<menu>`).

For more, please refer this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li

Seems Angular is intelligent enough to convert the string to integer. You may test with a non-number string which is converted to `0`, when rendered.

If you want to store any meta data, you may use something like this as template:

```
<li *ngFor="let company of companies" value="{{company.orgNr}}" 
     attr.data-vl="{{company.orgNr}}">
     {{company.name}} - {{company.orgNr}}
</li>
```

When rendered it looks like below:

```
<li value="123" data-vl="0000123">
        Google - 0000123
</li>
```

Hope this helps.